# get.month() in javascript returns wrong output with February

Tags: javascript

I have the problem that `getMonth()` fucntion in javascript returns a wrong value. I want to show the 5 months previous. The problem is now the date is 29/06/17 but for this year, February has 28 days. So it returns a wrong output to me. I have no ideas to solve this problem. If anyone know how to solve this problem please suggest me or tell me. Thank you.

[image]

```js
var month = [
  "January",
  "February",
  "March",
  "April",
  "May",
  "June",
  "July",
  "August",
  "September",
  "October",
  "November",
  "December"
];

var dt = new Date();

dt.setMonth(dt.getMonth());
var cur_month = month[dt.getMonth()];

dt.setMonth(dt.getMonth() - 1);
var pre_month_1 = month[dt.getMonth()];

dt.setMonth(dt.getMonth() - 1);
var pre_month_2 = month[dt.getMonth()];

dt.setMonth(dt.getMonth() - 1);
var pre_month_3 = month[dt.getMonth()];

dt.setMonth(dt.getMonth() - 1);
var pre_month_4 = month[dt.getMonth()];

dt.setMonth(dt.getMonth() - 1);
var pre_month_5 = month[dt.getMonth()];

document.getElementById("cur_month").innerHTML = cur_month;
document.getElementById("pre_month_1").innerHTML = pre_month_1;
document.getElementById("pre_month_2").innerHTML = pre_month_2;
document.getElementById("pre_month_3").innerHTML = pre_month_3;
document.getElementById("pre_month_4").innerHTML = pre_month_4;
document.getElementById("pre_month_5").innerHTML = pre_month_5;
```

```html
<select>
  <option id="yesterday" value="yesterday">Yesterday</option>
  <option id="cur_month" value="cur_month"></option>
  <option id="pre_month_1" value="pre_month_1"></option>
  <option id="pre_month_2" value="pre_month_2"></option>
  <option id="pre_month_3" value="pre_month_3"></option>
  <option id="pre_month_4" value="pre_month_4"></option>
  <option id="pre_month_5" value="pre_month_5"></option>
</select>
```

Comment: Just use momentjs

Comment: @Hackerman I didn't know about that and I will try it. Thank you :)

Comment: I use moment.js all the time and is awesome, but it is easier to use my answer in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the date to the first of the month: `dt.setDate(1);`

```js
var month = [
  "January",
  "February",
  "March",
  "April",
  "May",
  "June",
  "July",
  "August",
  "September",
  "October",
  "November",
  "December"
];

var dt = new Date();

// for month defining only
dt.setDate(1);

dt.setMonth(dt.getMonth());
var cur_month = month[dt.getMonth()];

dt.setMonth(dt.getMonth() - 1);
var pre_month_1 = month[dt.getMonth()];

dt.setMonth(dt.getMonth() - 1);
var pre_month_2 = month[dt.getMonth()];

dt.setMonth(dt.getMonth() - 1);
var pre_month_3 = month[dt.getMonth()];

dt.setMonth(dt.getMonth() - 1);
var pre_month_4 = month[dt.getMonth()];

dt.setMonth(dt.getMonth() - 1);
var pre_month_5 = month[dt.getMonth()];

document.getElementById("cur_month").innerHTML = cur_month;
document.getElementById("pre_month_1").innerHTML = pre_month_1;
document.getElementById("pre_month_2").innerHTML = pre_month_2;
document.getElementById("pre_month_3").innerHTML = pre_month_3;
document.getElementById("pre_month_4").innerHTML = pre_month_4;
document.getElementById("pre_month_5").innerHTML = pre_month_5;
```

```html
<select>
  <option id="yesterday" value="yesterday">Yesterday</option>
  <option id="cur_month" value="cur_month"></option>
  <option id="pre_month_1" value="pre_month_1"></option>
  <option id="pre_month_2" value="pre_month_2"></option>
  <option id="pre_month_3" value="pre_month_3"></option>
  <option id="pre_month_4" value="pre_month_4"></option>
  <option id="pre_month_5" value="pre_month_5"></option>
</select>
```